# How to fix Error: AnimatedValue: Attempting to set value to undefined - React Native

Tags: animation, react-native, react-animated

I Want to resize logo when keyboard show and hide .
these is the imgStyle.js

```
 import {StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native';

    const Height = Dimensions.get('screen');
    const height_logo = Height * 0.2;
    const height_logo_small = Height * 0.6;

    const IMAGE_HEIGHT = height_logo;

    const IMAGE_HEIGHT_SMALL = height_logo_small;
```

and this is main code .. (NOT FULL CODE)

```
     constructor(props) {
            super(props);
         this.imageHeight = new Animated.Value(IMAGE_HEIGHT);
              }
      
    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowSub = Keyboard.addListener(
          'keyboardDidShow',
          this.keyboardDidShow, );
        this.keyboardDidHideSub = Keyboard.addListener(
          'keyboardDidHide',
          this.keyboardDidHide,
        );
      }

  

componentWillUnmount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowSub.remove();
        this.keyboardDidHideSub.remove();
      }
      

keyboardDidShow = () => {
        Animated.timing(this.imageHeight, {
          toValue: IMAGE_HEIGHT_SMALL,
          duration: 5000,
        }).start();
      };
  

keyboardDidHide = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.imageHeight, {
      toValue: IMAGE_HEIGHT,
      duration: 5000,
    }).start();
  };
```

and this is the error :

> Error: AnimatedValue: Attempting to set value to undefined

anybody has this error or solved it?

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when trying to set `Animated.Value` to a boolean, rather than `0` or `1`.

`value` in both `Animated.Value(value)` and `setValue(value)` must be a number: [see documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animatedvalue#setvalue)

I needed to change this:

```js
const expanded = true;
const toggleAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(expanded)).current;
```

To this:

```js
const expanded = true;
const toggleAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(expanded ? 1 : 0)).current;
```

Or as @BradByte recommends in the comments, converting the boolean to a number:

```js
const expanded = true;
const toggleAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(Number(expanded))).current;
```

Comment: You can also wrap your boolean in a `Number()` to convert to an int. I.e. `new Animated.Value(Number(someBoolVal));`.

Answer (score 0):

the IMAGE_HEIGHT constant is not exported from imgStyle.js